# Can't log in to iTunes Connect : blank square?

Tags: app-store-connect

I haven't been able to connect to iTunes Connect for a few weeks... I have used Chrome on Linux and on a Mac. On Linux I see a white square on the login page after I log in, and on my mac the wheel keeps spinning for ever. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Trying on Safari and a slightly bigger screen :
my password expired and the blank screen was on Safari a screen asking to update the password.